# Lazy initialization

Tags: c#, .net, lazy-initialization

I am wondering what is the difference between two constructor overloads of `Lazy<T>` class.

> Lazy(Func, Boolean) - Initializes a new instance of the Lazy
>   class. When lazy initialization occurs, the specified initialization
>   function and initialization mode are used.
>
> Lazy(Func, LazyThreadSafetyMode) - Initializes a new instance of
>   the Lazy class that uses the specified initialization function and
>   thread-safety mode.

Is the second constructor more flexible from the point of thread-safety? Which `LazyThreadSafetyMode` member is an analogue for `Lazy<...>(..., true)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Reflector:

```
public Lazy(Func<T> valueFactory, bool isThreadSafe) : this(valueFactory, isThreadSafe ?LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication : LazyThreadSafetyMode.None)
{
}
```

So if you pass `true` it will convert to `LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication`.

`false` will convert to `LazyThreadSafetyMode.None`

By the way, if you only pass the value factor (omitting the bool altogether), it uses `LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication`.

Comment: And without resharper/reflector: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Lazy.cs#a7924544277182a9

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Oops, I meant Reflector of course. :) fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass `true` the object is initialized with the `ExecutionAndPublication` lazy mode. If you pass `false` the object is initialized with the `None` mode.

If you use an overload that does not take a boolean it is initialized with the `ExecutionAndPublication` mode.

Comment: oh, Matthew was quicker and found out the same way - I used Resharper too but would not dare to post disassembled code here :-)

Comment: I think it's ok to post it - after all, it's all freely available online here: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/